# Nested names in templates MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

I have some code and i can't understand, why it doesn't compile in `MSVC` (2010 Express, 2012 RC) and compile in other compilers (for example `gcc 4.7`). Is it bug in `MSVC` (i trying to search in google, but cannot find description of this bug), or i do something, that is not supported by standard?

```
template<typename T, T Val>
struct integral_c
{
    typedef integral_c<T, Val> type;
    static const T value = Val;
};

typedef integral_c<bool, true> true_;
typedef integral_c<bool, false> false_;

template<bool Cond, typename T = void>
struct enable_if
{
    typedef T type;
};

template<typename T>
struct enable_if<false, T>
{
};

template<typename T>
struct is_int : false_
{
};

template<>
struct is_int<int> : true_
{
};

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct identity_if_int
{
};

template<typename T>
struct identity_if_int<T, typename enable_if<is_int<T>::type::value>::type>
{
    typedef T type;
};

int main()
{
    identity_if_int<int>::type t = 0;
}
```

http://liveworkspace.org/code/311b71954b168862b19043ba49670856

`MSVC` says, that `enable_if<false>` has no member `type`. When i specialize `identity_if_int` like

```
template<typename T>
struct identity_if_int<T, typename enable_if<is_int<T>::value>::type>
{
    typedef T type;
};
```

all works correct. What is the problem? Any help and links to MSDN (or something else) will be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like an error in handling `is_int<T>::type::value`.  Both `is_int<T>::value` and `identity<typename is_int<T>::type>::type::value` work as expected.  I'm not familiar enough with the complexities of name lookup, templates, and Visual C++'s nonstandard name lookup to know whether this is a bug; someone else may be able to confirm.  If you'd like, please open a bug on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) and post back here with a link for future reference (I don't see any existing bug that is an obvious match for this issue).

Comment: I suspect your gcc code is using the boost definition of enable_if. The c++11 definition of std::enable_if is different, like boost::enable_if_c. If that's it, tell me and I will add it as answer.

Comment: @JiveDadson my code use my own definition of enable-if, not boost, or c++11.

Comment: @ForEveR Oops. Missed that. Neeeever mind.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis link on my feedback http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/759874/nested-names-in-templates-c

Comment: @ForEveR -- post that as an answer and I'll give you an upvote...